# Cron Job not working

Tags: wordpress

i use WP und civicrm. For Cron-Jobs i use [www.cron-jobs.org](http://www.cron-jobs.org).

I insert the following informations:

```
URL: http://www.myurl.de/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php

POST: name=username&pass=password&key=myOwnSite-Key&job=process_mailing
```

The Job say successfully.

Request:

```
POST /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.myurl.de
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; cron-job.org; http://cron-job.org/abuse/)
Accept: */*
X-Forwarded-For: ip.ip.ip.ip (my IP)
Content-Length: 91
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
name=user&pass=pass&key=myOwnSite-Key&job=process_mailing
```

Result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2022 16:18:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix)
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.7
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=someFunnyIDCode; path=/
Content-Length: 0
```

But civicrm tell me that no cron job was running :-(

```
Set-Up Cron
Es wurde kein Cron Lauf aufgezeichnet.
Ein Cron Job ist notwendig für die automatische Ausführung von Geplanten Aufgaben.
(Weiterlesen...)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about your specific problem, but it may be interesting to try running the same call manually (using curl or postman), to see if that works again. If that works with curl or postman, you can try using another service, like https://cronit.app for instance and see if the result is the same.